# Swiper slide brakes after hide images with [display: "none"]

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I really need help with this. I'm building a slider with swiper js

I have a product with few options, the idea is to filter the images that don't match with the option selected.

I know swiper has a lot of method and events, but the closest I found was the removeSlide and add/append Slide, which eliminates the element from the DOM. So I did it with plain javascript, hidden the images with css like this:

```
if (event.target.name.includes("Color")){
            
           images.forEach((image)=>{
            if (!image.dataset.thumbColor.includes(color)){
              image.classList.add('hidden');
              swiper.swiper.update();
              swiper2.swiper.update();
            }
          });
        
           thumbs.forEach((thumb)=>{
            if (!thumb.dataset.thumbColor.includes(color)){
              thumb.classList.add('hidden');
            } else {
              thumb.addEventListener('click',()=>{
              swiper2.swiper.slideTo(thumb.dataset.slideNum);
            })
            }
            }); 

            
          }
```

The problem whit this (like you can see in the link below) is that after the first filter, when you click a thumb image it doesn't send you anymore to the correct image.

https://e9ef6jlcbp604898-59185856680.shopifypreview.com

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try `swiper.update()` after manually manipulating your slides.

Ref: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-update

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I keep investigating and Swiper it's not the best alternative to use for this functionality

Comment: There are a few out there but choosing one that fits your needs as close as possible is always a good route!